# Import column with large int values from sqlite

Tags: r, sqlite, data.table

I have a sqlite DB that includes columns with int values that are too big for R to handle. Is it still possible to import those columns in R in a way that those big int values will not be converted in a strange way?

What i do so far:

```
library(DBI)
library(RSQLite)
library(data.table)

# connect to the sqlite file
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), 'test.sqlite')
# get the perormance_data as a data.frame -> data.table
p1 = dbGetQuery(con,'
SELECT
    Post.post_id,
    Post.created_time
FROM
    Post
            ')
p1 <- as.data.table(p1)
```

The `post_id`-column includes large int values for example.

Comment: you may also want to look at the `bit64` package which i believe plays well with `data.tabe`

Comment: SQLite driver **may** limit integer size besides having `bit64`. Safe is always go via character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest -  as long as you don't need to do arithmetics on the large value - should be to just import it as a string;

```
library(DBI)
library(RSQLite)
library(data.table)

# connect to the sqlite file
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), 'test.sqlite')
# get the perormance_data as a data.frame -> data.table
p1 = dbGetQuery(con,'
SELECT
    CAST(Post.post_id AS VARCHAR) post_id,
    Post.created_time
FROM
    Post
            ')
p1 <- as.data.table(p1)
p1
```

Comment: exactly what i was looking for! *new to sql*

Comment: `dbGetQuery` returns a `data.frame`? If so, it's better practice to use `setDT(p1)` to convert without copies

Comment: @MichaelChirico yes a `data.frame` is returned. Thanks for the advice - will do it your way from now on!